# Financial Slang and NLP for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: algorithm, twitter, nlp, finance, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a Sentiment-Analysis/Opinion-Mining of Tweets, focused on Finance related tweets.

One of the biggest issue I'm facing is the unability of my algorithm to detect equivalent entities (Definition in B.Liu 2012: [Page 18-19](https://www.cs.uic.edu/%7Eliub/FBS/SentimentAnalysis-and-OpinionMining.pdf)) when Financial slang is used. For example, for those familiar with it I would like the following entities to be detected as equivalent after lemmatization :

- Government-Bonds = Govies = Sovereign-Debt
- Cash = Monetary
- Stocks = Equities
- FX = Forex = Currency-exchange = Foreign-Exchange
- Bund = German-Bonds = Bundesbank 10y
- T-Notes = US10 = Treasury-Notes = US-Govies = American-Sovereign-Debt
- Etc...

Here are my two questions :

1. I was thinking about using some supervised learning (Naive-Bayesian-Classification) for such task, but can't find any classified set of data for training. Do you know if such dataset exists?
2. Do you have any alternative idea regarding how to perform such task?

Thanks.

Comment: You could train a system for Named Entity Recognition to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a simple dataset programmatically searching Google for news summaries that match your classes. The returned summaries form your training dataset (multiple classes). Once trained, you pass each new (relevant) tweet through the model.

**Building The Dataset**

[Here](https://gist.github.com/nirmalyaghosh/e31dfcdf36ab6020c35db81af21582d6) is some code which help scrape news summaries. It is based on 
[this](https://www.kaggle.com/steubk/home-depot-product-search-relevance/fixing-typos) notebook posted on Kaggle. Just modify your search accordingly.

Some examples with results returned back (*snipped for brevity*) ,

- `"Sovereign-Debt"+Government-Bonds`, returns

  - *"**Government bonds** gained, with the one-year yield falling three basis .."*
  - *"Russian **sovereign debt** dropped for a third day as oil traded near a four-month low .."*
- `"T-Notes"`, returns

  - *"Speculators reduced their net bullish bets on U.S. 10-year **Treasury note** futures from their highest levels since late 2012, according to .."*
  - *"The U.S. Department of the Treasury holds seven-year **T-notes** (**Treasury notes**) auctions every month .."*

**Training Dataset**

Your training dataset would be similar to the following (sentence, label) tuples,

- (*".. becomes sort of safe haven carry vehicle vs 1.7% on 10y **US govies**, Brexit .."*, `Treasury Notes`)
- (*"Speculators reduced their net bullish bets on U.S. 10-year **Treasury note** futures from their highest levels since late 2012"*, `Treasury Notes`)
- (*"Speculators net longs in US 10-year **T-notes** highest since 2012"*, `Treasury Notes`)
- (*"US **stocks** rise to record highs after payrolls boost"*, `Stocks`)
- (*"European **Equity** Benchmarks Close Mixed; Auto **Stocks** Slump.."*, `Stocks`)
- (*"In Switzerland, **government bonds** through the longest maturity .."*, `Government Bonds`)
- (*".. about $1.6 trillion worth of negative-yielding **sovereign debt** .."*, `Government Bonds`)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, looks exactly like what I need. Thank you. Let me just dig a little further into it! thanks.